# Un mismo sitio web con diferentes detalles

Tags: php, html

Tengo la siguiente situacion y me gustaria pedirles sus consejos y ver de que manera puedo solicionar esto.

Ya tengo un sitio web creado, en el ingresan los usuarios sin problema, la consulta es como puedo hacer para que cada usuarios tenga partes o diseños diferentes en el mismo sitio, por ejemplo si Juan y Luis son usuarios, como hago para que Juan tenga una opción mas en el menú o que Luis tenga diferentes colores en la página,

Como se podria hacer algo asi ?

Gracias por la ayuda

**ACTUALIZACION**

Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas y comentarios, me parece que la opción de roles puede ser que no se acople muy bien aca, hice este imagen para aclarar mas la consulta, el punto es que todo usuario ve el sitio web completo de igual forma (digamos 10 paginas), ahora, cada usuario por separado puede ver o tener acceso a paginas que haya soliciatod crear para el, en la siguiente imagen **LUIS** va a ver todo el sitio web mas las páginas de Mapa, Video y Tablas que el solicitó crear para el, en su caso **JUAN** va a poder ver todo el sitio web mas la página de Galeria y la de Graficos que el pidio crear para el, ese es el punto de la consulta, espero que con esto se aclare mas la consulta, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para eso puedes establecer roles de usuario y guardarlos en variables de sesión.

Comment: Puedes asignar roles a los usuarios y dependiendo del rol podrias generar una vista u otra.

Comment: Yo estoy más de acuerdo a que sean por medio de roles y a esos roles, les darás accesos a ciertas vistas y/o funciones